# Optimize a MDX Query

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I am quite new to MDX and I need some help with this query.

```
Generate( 
    filter( 
      [Dim Products].[Product].[Product].members 
        * 
      [Dim Date].week.week.members, 
      [Measures].[Price] 
      ), 
      nonempty( 
        topcount( 
          [Dim Price].[Price].[Price] 
            *
          [Dim Products].[Product].currentmember 
            * 
          [Dim Date].week.currentmember, 
          1, 
          [Measures].[Price Count] 
          )
      )
   )
```

I am using the above Named Set in a dashboard tool (Dundas Dashboard) in order to retrieve the MODE (price value that repeats the most). It does show correct results however it is slow. It takes 2-3 seconds if there is a filter on a single week and takes about 6-7 seconds if there is no filter on week (shows data for all weeks). And this is in SSMS but the client tool takes even longer to get the result set, sometimes timing out.

After some tests it appears that the number of the rows in the fact table does not affect the performance, I've drastically decreased it but still the same. The performance increased, however, once I've decreased the number of members in 2 of the dimension tables - `[Dim Price], [Dim Products].` Initially it was taking 20+ seconds to get result set but improved to 6-7 seconds once I've decreased the number of members as follows:

```
Table          | Rows Before | Rows After
[Dim Price]    | 2400        | 620 
[Dim Products] | 1080        | 101
```

This makes me think there is a Cartesian Product between the 3 dimensions that is affecting the performance.

I need someone to advise how I can improve the query to increase the performance.

Comment: `EXISTING` is sometimes a good addition for performance. There are no hard-and-fast rules about `MDX` performance - even Chris Webb says experience halps but playing around with alternative approaches is a good idea.

Comment: What is the condition of your filter? Isn't the third argument usually something like `[Measures].[Price] > 10000`?

Comment: ok - lets delete them

Comment: @JoshGallagher do you understand the second argument he is using in the `filter` function `[Measures].[Price]` ? What does this do - should it not include some condition e.g. `[Measures].[Price] > 0`?

Comment: No, I don't understand the second filter argument. It should evaluate to a true or false value, not a numeric one.

Answer (score 0):

Try the EXISTING function before the NONEMPTY function like this:

```
Generate( 
filter( 
  [Dim Products].[Product].[Product].members 
    * 
  [Dim Date].week.week.members, 
  [Measures].[Price]  //<<<<<<<<<<SHOULD THIS NOT INCLUDE A CONDITION e.g. [Measures].[Price] > 0 ?
  ), 
  EXISTING nonempty( 
    topcount( 
      [Dim Price].[Price].[Price] 
        *
      [Dim Products].[Product].currentmember 
        * 
      [Dim Date].week.currentmember, 
      1, 
      [Measures].[Price Count] 
      )
  )
```

)

Attempt 2:

```
Generate( 
    filter( 
      NONEMPTY(
        [Dim Products].[Product].[Product].members 
          * 
        [Dim Date].week.week.members, 
        [Measures].[Price]  
        )
      ), 
      EXISTING nonempty( 
        topcount( 
          [Dim Price].[Price].[Price] 
            *
          [Dim Products].[Product].currentmember 
            * 
          [Dim Date].week.currentmember, 
          1, 
          [Measures].[Price Count] 
          )
      )
   )
```

Attempt 3:

```
GENERATE( 
  FILTER( 
    NONEMPTY(
      [Dim Products].[Product].[Product].MEMBERS 
        * 
      [Dim Date].week.week.MEMBERS
        ), 
    [Measures].[Price] > 0 
  ), 
  TOPCOUNT( 
    NONEMPTY(
            EXISTING 
            [Dim Price].[Price].[Price] 
            *
            [Dim Products].[Product].currentmember 
            * 
            [Dim Date].week.currentmember,
      [Measures].[Price Count] 
      ), 
    1, 
    [Measures].[Price Count] 
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you whytheq. I tried including a condition to filter and also to add Existing before nonempty but none of them makes any difference unfortunately. Don't know what else I can try.

Comment: maybe a NONEMPTY around the first `[Dim Products].[Product].[Product].members * [Dim Date].week.week.members`. I'll add to post.

Comment: Still no difference, sorry. I am thinking that the actual problem is with [Dim Price].[Price].[Price] in topcount. Maybe I need to make sure it only gets the prices that appear against the current product & week. Not sure if it does it by default or if it first does a cartesian product between all prices * current product & week and then filter the results.

Comment: if you do * on two hierarchies from different dimensions then by default it is a cartesian product - that is what * does. I've added in another nonempty but lost track of the braces now!

Comment: @user2849258 please feel free to amend my post - the second arg of the filter is still down as `[Measures].[Price]` I'll change this to a proper filter Boolean